# magit merge conflict `checkout --theirs/--ours`

Tags: emacs, magit

Sometimes when resolving a git conflict, I'll know that one side is better for a file and I'll resolve it with `git checkout --theirs path/to/file`.

However it is not obvious how to do this in magit, so I always drop to the CLI to do it. Is it possible to do this easily?

Answer (score 7):

On the next branch (what will be 2.1.0), when you are rebasing and discard a conflict ('k'), you will be prompted and have the option to select `--theirs`.  You can also call `magit-checkout-stage` directly and select the file and `--theirs` flag.

For version 1.2.*, I think using Ediff with `magit-interactive-resolve` is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the arrows at the head of the conflict

```
<<<<<<<< HEAD
```

a menu will appear and will let you select the appropriate action.